# Pandas delete row based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

```
print (amazon.shape)
print (amazon.drop(amazon[(amazon["Id"] > 150492) & (amazon["Id"] < 150530 )].index).shape)
print (amazon.shape)
```

output :

```
(525814, 10)
(525782, 10)
(525814, 10)
```

why is it not deleting 32 rows from main dataframe .?

Comment: because `drop` not inplace, you need write `drop(your code, inplace=True)` without print. or `amazon = amazon.drop(amazon....)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `drop`'s [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) (emphasis mine):

> DataFrame.drop(labels=None, axis=0, index=None, columns=None,
>   level=None, **inplace=False**, errors='raise')
>
> inplace : bool, default False
>
> If True, do operation inplace and return None.

`drop` is not inplace by default. You have to explictly tell it to be:

```
amazon.drop(amazon[(amazon["Id"] > 150492) & (amazon["Id"] < 150530 )].index, inplace=True)
```

Or reassign it back to `amazon` (or to anything else):

```
amazon = amazon.drop(amazon[(amazon["Id"] > 150492) & (amazon["Id"] < 150530 )].index)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do add the argument inplace=True otherwise it just returns a copy of the data frame with the row dropped.